# Visualizing a Node Tree (Repulsion?)

Tags: javascript, data-structures, tree, visualization

I need to visualize a Node Tree for a project I'm working on... The datastructure looks like this:

**Constructor Functions:**

```
function Tree(x,y,node){
    this.root = node;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

function Node(key,parent,data){
    this.children = new Array();
    this.key = key;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.data = data;
    this.direction = ???;
}
```

Every `children` Array can hold more nodes, so that I get a Tree structure... The `x` and `y` value of `Tree` is used to get the position, where the root of the Tree should be drawn, while the `direction` property of `Node` stores the angle, in which the `Node` should be drawn depending on the `parent` angle....

So now to my problem: I need a function `draw(context)` for the `Tree.prototype` that can draw the `Tree` using the given canvas context.

Here is an example of how such a `Tree` should look like:

[image]

I actually had an idea for how such an algorithm could work, but I couldn't convert it into code... Here it is:

*Every node pushes away other nodes. The force is depending on the distance between Nodes and their level (root is level 0, it's children are level 1 and so on...).*

I imagine, that after a few itereations a nice looking Tree will be created...

A huge thanks to you already in case you try to help me or even attempt to create such an algorithm...

EDIT:

Here is what I tried so far:

```
Tree.prototype.repulsion = function(){
    if(this.root){
        this.root.repulsion();
    }
};
Node.prototype.repulsion = function(){
    var force = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
    var pos = {
        x: this.x,
        y: this.y
    };
    var oldDirection = this.direction;
    for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
        var node = nodes[i];
        if(node!=this){
            var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pos.x-node.x,2)+Math.pow(pos.y-node.y,2));
            var direction = Math.atan((this.y-node.y)/(this.x-node.x));
            var magnitude = 1/Math.pow(distance,2);
            if(pos.x<node.x){
                direction *= -1;
                force.x -= Math.cos(direction)*magnitude;
            }else{
                force.x += Math.cos(direction)*magnitude;
            }
            force.y += Math.sin(direction)*magnitude;
        }
    }
    force.x *= repulsionFactor;
    force.y *= repulsionFactor;
    var newPos = {
        x: pos.x+force.x,
        y: pos.y+force.y
    };
    var newDirection = Math.atan((newPos.y-this.parent.y)/(newPos.x-this.parent.x));
    if(force.x<0){
        newDirection += Math.PI;
    }
    this.direction = newDirection;
    this.direction %= 2*Math.PI;
    for(var i=0;i<this.children.length;i++){
        this.children[i].repulsion();
    }
};
```

Comment: This is an interesting problem to solve, I'll try to make suck the algorithm. I've found a document discussing this problem. http://www.cs.unc.edu/techreports/89-034.pdf I'll come and post an answer if I successfully implement it.

Comment: @RomainIsnel Thanks a lot :) I actually stumbled across this article as well, but I think my english and coding skills are to low for this kind of stuff... I'm looking forward to your solution.

Comment: I might need one or two days to implement this solution since I since got work to do aside from that, but I'll definitely give it a try.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not in a hurry... I actually try to solve this since a week, so a few days more or less won't make a big difference :)

Comment: Your algorithm needs some work, you also need a force that pulls two edge-connected nodes together. You'll want to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us your attempt at implementing the algorithm. It shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: You should store the coordinates for the nodes as well, not just a chain of `direction`s from the root. You will need to calculate lots of distances between unrelated nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually got my own idea to work!

```js
var tree, width, height, clock, lastCalledTime, root, node, 
 repulsionFactor = 10000,
 nodes = new Array();

function setup(){
 tree = new Tree(200,200);
 tree.repulsionFactor = 10000;
 for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  tree.addRandomChild();
 }
 for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
  tree.addRandomChild(1);
 }
 for(var i=0;i<15;i++){
  tree.addRandomChild(2);
 }
 root = tree.root;
 node = root.children[0];
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 width = 400;
 height = 400;
 canvas.width = width;
 canvas.height = height;
 canvasSize = {x:window.innerWidth-5,y:window.innerHeight-5};
 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 clock = requestAnimationFrame(main);
 //clock = setInterval(main,200);
}

function main(){
 if(!lastCalledTime) {
  lastCalledTime = Date.now();
 }
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
 tree.repulsion();
 tree.draw();
 var delta = (Date.now() - lastCalledTime)/1000;
 lastCalledTime = Date.now();
 var fps = 1/delta;
    tree.repulsionFactor*=0.99;
 clock = requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

function Tree(x,y){
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.nodeColor = "gray";
 this.lineColor = "black";
 this.size = 20;
 this.lineWidth = 3;
 this.linkLength = 100;
 this.nodes = new Array();
 this.repulsionFactor = 10000;
 this.root = new Node(this,this,"root");
}

Tree.prototype.addRandomChild = function(level=0){
 var node = this.root;
 for(var i=0;i<level;i++){
  if(node.children.length>0){
   var randIndex = Math.floor(node.children.length*Math.random());
   node = node.children[randIndex];
  }else{
   return false;
  }
 }
 node.addChild();
};

Tree.prototype.draw = function(){
 this.root.draw();
}

Tree.prototype.repulsion = function(){
 this.root.repulsion();
};

Tree.prototype.level = -1;
Tree.prototype.direction = 0;

function Node(parent,tree,key,data,direction){
 this.children = new Array();
 this.parent = parent;
 this.tree = tree;
 this.key = key;
 this.data = data;
 if(direction){
  this.direction = direction;
 }else{
  this.direction = this.parent.direction+Math.random()/10;
 }
 this.tree.nodes.push(this);
}

Node.prototype.addChild = function(key,data){
 this.children.push(new Node(this,this.tree,key,data));
};

Node.prototype.draw = function(){
 ctx.fillStyle = this.nodeColor;
 ctx.strokeStyle = this.lineColor;
 ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
 if(this.key!="root"){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(this.x,this.y);
  ctx.lineTo(this.parent.x,this.parent.y);
  ctx.stroke();
 }
 for(var i=0;i<this.children.length;i++){
  this.children[i].draw();
 }
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.size,0,2*Math.PI,false);
 ctx.fill();
 ctx.stroke();
}

Node.prototype.repulsion = function(){
 if(this.key!="root"){
  var force = {
   x: 0,
   y: 0
  };
  var pos = {
   x: this.x,
   y: this.y
  };
  var nodes = this.tree.nodes;
  for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
   var node = nodes[i];
   if(node!=this){
    var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pos.x-node.x,2)+Math.pow(pos.y-node.y,2));
    var direction = Math.atan2((pos.y-node.y),(pos.x-node.x));
    var magnitude = 1/Math.pow(distance,2)/(node.level+1);
    force.x += Math.cos(direction)*magnitude;
    force.y += Math.sin(direction)*magnitude;
   }
  }
  force.x *= this.tree.repulsionFactor;
  force.y *= this.tree.repulsionFactor;
  var newPos = {
   x: pos.x+force.x,
   y: pos.y+force.y
  };
  var newDirection = Math.atan2((newPos.y-this.parent.y),(newPos.x-this.parent.x));
  this.direction = newDirection;
 }else{
  this.direction = this.parent.direction;
 }
 for(var i=0;i<this.children.length;i++){
  this.children[i].repulsion();
 }
};



Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype,"x",{
 get: function x(){
  if(this.key=="root"){
   return this.parent.x;
  }
  return Math.cos(this.direction)*this.linkLength+this.parent.x;
 }
});

Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype,"y",{
 get: function y(){
  if(this.key=="root"){
   return this.parent.y;
  }
  return Math.sin(this.direction)*this.linkLength+this.parent.y;
 }
});

Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype,"level",{
 get: function level(){
  return this.parent.level+1;
 }
});

Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype,"nodeColor",{
 get: function nodeColor(){
  return this.parent.nodeColor;
 }
});

Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype,"lineColor",{
 get: function lineColor(){
  return this.parent.lineColor;
 }
});

Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype,"lineWidth",{
 get: function lineWidth(){
  return this.parent.lineWidth;
 }
});

Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype,"size",{
 get: function size(){
  return this.parent.size*0.8;
 }
});

Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype,"linkLength",{
 get: function linkLength(){
  return this.parent.linkLength*0.8;
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Node Tree</title>
 </head>
 <body onload="setup()">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

For some reason the tree keeps spinning sometimes, and also not every time I create a tree it unfolds... But hopefully you can expand on this!

Comment: If you upped the initial `repulsionFactor` by adding an extra `0`, then you can be pretty sure it unfolds. To combat the wiggly-ness and the rotation, you could gradually lower the repulsion rate in your `main` function using something like: `tree.repulsionFactor *= 0.99;`. If you need to add a node later, you could reset the `repulsionFactor` to the high value and then slow it down again.

Comment: That's actually great ! That's what you were looking for @Anton Ballmaier. Pretty good job I would say.

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen Thanks, looks like it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Something link this?

I use the number of descendants to push nodes away from their respective root. That combined with some angle modification based on level makes it highly unlikely, but not impossible, to get overlapping notes.

```js
var Branch = (function() {
  function Branch(parent, key, data) {
    if (parent === void 0) {
      parent = null;
    }
    if (key === void 0) {
      key = "test";
    }
    if (data === void 0) {
      data = "null";
    }
    this.parent = parent;
    this.key = key;
    this.data = data;
    this.children = [];
    this.pos = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    };
    if (this.parent != null) {
      this.parent.children.push(this);
    }
  }
  Branch.prototype.level = function() {
    if (this.parent != null) {
      return this.parent.level() + 1;
    }
    return 0;
  };
  Branch.prototype.descendants = function() {
    var count = 0;

    function descent(target) {
      count += target.children.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < target.children.length; i++) {
        descent(target.children[i]);
      }
    }
    descent(this);
    return count;
  };
  return Branch;
}());
var Tree = (function() {
  function Tree(pos, node) {
    this.pos = pos;
    this.node = node;
    this.node.pos = this.pos;
  }
  Tree.prototype.render = function(canvas, padding, nodeSize, longpath, showText) {
    if (padding === void 0) {
      padding = 100;
    }
    if (nodeSize === void 0) {
      nodeSize = 10;
    }
    if (longpath === void 0) {
      longpath = 4;
    }
    if (showText === void 0) {
      showText = true;
    }
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //flatten
    var flattened = [];

    function getLevel(branch) {
      flattened.push(branch);
      for (var index = 0; index < branch.children.length; index++) {
        getLevel(branch.children[index]);
      }
    }
    getLevel(this.node);
    //disperse
    function disperseLevel(branch) {
      if (branch.parent != null) {
        branch.pos.x = branch.parent.pos.x;
        branch.pos.y = branch.parent.pos.y;
        var angle = (((360 / (branch.parent.children.length + branch.level())) * branch.parent.children.indexOf(branch)) + (branch.level() * 10)) * Math.PI / 180;
        branch.pos.x += Math.cos(angle) * (padding * (branch.descendants() / longpath + 1));
        branch.pos.y += Math.sin(angle) * (padding * (branch.descendants() / longpath + 1));
      }
      for (var index = 0; index < branch.children.length; index++) {
        disperseLevel(branch.children[index]);
      }
    }
    disperseLevel(this.node);
    //draw
    for (var index = 0; index < flattened.length; index++) {
      var branch = flattened[index];
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + (255 - ((branch.level()) * 48) % 255).toString() + ',0,0,1)';
      ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(" + (255 - ((branch.level()) * 48) % 255).toString() + ',0,0,1)';
      ctx.fillRect(branch.pos.x - (0.5 * nodeSize), branch.pos.y - (0.5 * nodeSize), nodeSize, nodeSize);
      if (branch.parent != null) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(branch.pos.x, branch.pos.y);
        ctx.lineTo(branch.parent.pos.x, branch.parent.pos.y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
      }
      if (showText === true) {
        ctx.strokeText(branch.key + ': ' + branch.data, branch.pos.x, branch.pos.y);
      }
    }
  };
  return Tree;
}());
//TEST
//setup canvas
var c = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.width = 3000;
c.height = 3000;
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.font = "14px Arial";
//create nodes
var key = 1;
var nodes = [
  new Branch(null, (key++).toString(), "ROOT")
];
//create tree
var tree = new Tree({
  x: 1000,
  y: 1000
}, nodes[0]);
//render tree using canvas
setInterval(function() {
  if (nodes.length > 50) {
    return true;
  }
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  nodes.push(new Branch(nodes[Math.floor(Math.random() * (nodes.length - 1))], (key++).toString()));
  tree.render(c, 100, 10, 4, true);
}, 100);
```

Comment: It kind of works, but since my goal is to make it visually pleasing, pushing nodes further and further away isn't really an option :/ I really appreciate your work, but I think this isn't, what I'm gonna go with... There are some intresting ideas behind your code what so ever :)